# Why do advertisements use Flash?

Tags: flash, ads

Why do almost all ads use Flash rather than HTML, CSS, and Javascript? There are very simple advertisements (for example, with a single hover effect) all over the place that are for some reason rendered in Flash. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside other things: more popular and comfortable tools for developing those. Use less bandwidth (SWF is an archive with the payload optimized for streaming, while HTML isn't optimized for that / it is up to the server to compress it, it comes in chunks, which requires multiple requests).
Ad-exchange networks would rather have a generic solution for ads of various complexity, so having a special case for primitive ads, which can be designed using an alternative technology is an extra work.

Answer (score 0):

One reason is to isolate styling. It's a pain when a page's css effects the rendering of an ad.